# Convert an object interface to a typed array with the correct index order in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Is there a more programmatic way to achieve something like this?

```
interface objType {
    prop1: {...};
    prop2: {...};
    prop3: {...}
}

type arrayType = [objType['prop1'], objType['prop2'], objType['prop3']];
```

Ideally I don't want to have to update the `arrayType` whenever another property is added to `objType`

Comment: You can convert the `arrayType` to the `objType`. But not the other way around; would that be ok for you?

Comment: @TobiasS. Having the `arrayType` as the one source of truth is an interesting work around I hadn't considered. If `objType` to `arrayType` is not possible this may have to be my fallback

Comment: For one thing, you haven't given the rule for the order of the properties in the array.

Comment: Object types don't have property ordering so there's no way to guarantee that the compiler will put things in the order you expect .  Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w61pEW) work instead? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?  (Please @jcalz mention me if you reply; I won't get notified otherwise)

Comment: @jcalz yeah as you and @ Tobias S. have pointed out, it doesn't seem possible to convert from object to array. In which case your approach to convert from array type to object type works well